# Cisco Aironet 3702i AP standalone - clients do not get DHCP from router

Tags: cisco, dhcp, access-point

I have two APs in standalone mode right now because the controller is broken. I have configured DHCP server in the router (L3 switch) but the clients do not get IP. Laptop connected to the router got IP from the DHCP server.

So, I think the problem is related to DHCP relay but I am not sure what.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check ***SSID VLAN mapping*** on the AP configuration GUI . you must map the SSID to the proper VLAN to get IP in its range . make use of the [NEXT LINK](http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/support/docs/interfaces-modules/security-modules-routers-switches/116586-config-ap-00.html)

Comment: it is mapped to the correct VLAN. Currently I have not configured anything besides VLAN 1 on the APs and the switch because I want to make sure everything works at the very basic level. The VLAN 1 is configured as native in the APs and the switch.

Comment: Native Vlan may be used only for management so may you need to configure other vlan for data rather than the native one . OR you may try to put the AP in vlan 1 access port in the switch (not trunk)

Comment: I created another SSID in VLAN2 and a new DHCP pool in the switch. I leave the switch port in the trunk mode. It works. So, normal data cannot use VLAN1. Thank you very much. Can the client roaming to another AP if I use the same SSID in another AP?

Comment: sure within same VLAN and same SSID